# How do I get the following information out of a solaris sparc machine?

Tags: hardware, solaris, processor, bios, sparc

-Processor Id
-baseboard manufacturer and 
-serial number of the bios

For the x86 solaris I got it from smbios but when I run smbios on a solaris sparc, it gives me an error message:
smbios: failed to load SMBIOS: System does not export an SMBIOS table

I would also like to get the information programmatically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no surprise. SPARC machines do not make use of a BIOS but what is called the Open Boot PROM.

Here are some commands that will help you gathering information from your machine:

```
prtdiag
prtconf
prtfru
psrinfo -v
sneep
```

Comment: what are the information that I can get on a SPARC that differs from machine to machine other than the MAC address?

Comment: oh and how can I get those information out programmatically?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is plenty of information that can differ from machine to machine on both SPARC and x86. There is no single API to get it programmatically.